# MariaDB: Querying a timestamp partition

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning, mariadb, query-performance

I'm having difficulties getting my queries to make use of the partitions when I'm selecting. They need to be able to do `> sometime` `> sometime` and `between sometime and anothertime`. However, if I do anything other than a straight equality check, MariaDB uses all the partitions.

This is how I have my table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events
(
  time TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id, time)
)
-- Need to take the FLOOR. See  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_timestamp/
PARTITION BY RANGE (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time))) (
  PARTITION p20150801 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-01 00:00:00'))),
  PARTITION p20150807 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-07 00:00:00'))),
  PARTITION p20150814 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-14 00:00:00'))),
  PARTITION p20150821 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-21 00:00:00'))),
  PARTITION p20150828 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-28 00:00:00'))),
  PARTITION p20150830 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-30 00:00:00')))
);
```

And this is how my query is using the partions.

```
MariaDB [events]> explain partitions select * from events where time > TIMESTAMP("2015-08-27T01:02:03");                                                                                                           
+------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table  | partitions                                                  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | events | p20150801,p20150807,p20150814,p20150821,p20150828,p20150830 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [events]> explain partitions select * from events where time = TIMESTAMP("2015-08-27T01:02:03");                                                                                                           
+------+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | events | p20150828  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. This has me tearing out my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is too complex.  There are many severe limitations of what can go into `BY RANGE`.  Use simply `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)`.  Even if it would work, `FLOOR` does not add anything to the expression.

BTW, the trailing hh:mm:ss is optional in this situation.  These are identical:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-01 00:00:00')
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-01')
```

Now, on to my favorite question:  Why are you using `PARTITIONing`?  `PARTITIONing`does not inherently provide any performance.  There are only a few use cases I know of where you can trick `PARTITION` into providing more performance than a carefully chosen index.